# Range.find method to find cells with specific colorindex

Tags: excel, vba, find

I want to find cells with the same colorindex with a range
So I recorded a macro to find cells with a color 
and applied to its code like this.
But it doesn't work.

How can I find cells with a specific colorindex?

```
For Each r In rngC
lcolorID = r.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
     With wsD.UsedRange
          With Application.FindFormat.Interior
         .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .Color = lcolorID
          End With
      Set c = .Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell,  _ 
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _ 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False, _ 
SearchFormat:=True)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print c.Address
        End If
   End With
Next r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = yourColorIndex Then 'using your color variable 
    'your actions here
End If
```

Place the above if condition in a for loop where you go through all the rows and it should work! And replace "Cell" by the specific cell you are currently handling in the project using the loop you are using to go through your sheet. If your sheet name is `"Sheet"` then use:

```
Sheets("Sheet").Cell(rowindex, columnindex).Interior.ColorIndex
```

Where `rowindex` and `columnindex` are the indexes your are looping through.

Comment: Can I use the Range.Find Method?

Comment: Not sure Find method supports `Cell.Interior.ColorIndex` searches but you can try: 
`Range(Sheets("Sheet").Cell(startingrow, startingcolumn), Sheets("Sheet").Cell(endrow, endcolumn)).Find(yourColorIndex)`

Comment: i wanted a way to use Range.find method using colorindex. but it seems to me almost impossible. anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `Application.FindFormat.Clear` before `With Application.FindFormat.Interior`.

You may have some formatting already set which may prevent you in matching desired cells.

Comment: i tried it, then it worked only in "solid" color cells such as yellow, blue..... it didn't work in other "tinted" or "shaded" colors. anyway, thanks!

Comment: @KevinKim If it didn't work, you shouldn't mark answer as correct.